# meanbean: failed to test bean with arrays

Tags: java

I am using mean bean 'http://meanbean.sourceforge.net' to validate/test my beans. It works fine for most of the beans. But when a bean has arrays in it, it is failing with following error.

```
SEVERE: getFactory: Failed to find suitable Factory for property=[hostNames] of type=[class [I]. Please register a custom Factory. Throw NoSuchFactoryException.
org.meanbean.factories.ObjectCreationException: Failed to instantiate object of type [[I] due to NoSuchMethodException.
```

Following is my sample code.

```
public class Machine {
private String[] hostNames;

public String[] getHostNames() {
    return hostNames;
}

public void setHostNames(String[] hostNames) {
    this.hostNames = hostNames;
}
```

}

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.meanbean.test.BeanTester;

public class TestBeanUtil {
    @Test
     public void test1(){
        new BeanTester().testBean(Machine.class);
    }
 }
```

Any help on how to get rid of this error. I found one way by ignoring specific fields like below.

```
Configuration configuration = new     ConfigurationBuilder().ignoreProperty("hostNames").build();

new BeanTester().testBean(Machine.class, configuration);
```

But My concern is is there any way that i can test without ignoring specific proper (or) ignore all the arrays in one shot ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe too late, but you can include in the **AbstractJavaBeanTest** the factories of each property that cannot be created.

Here is a sample when you need a factory for LocalDateTime and UUID

```
@Test
public void getterAndSetterCorrectness() throws Exception
{
    final BeanTester beanTester = new BeanTester();
    beanTester.getFactoryCollection().addFactory(LocalDateTime.class,
            new LocalDateTimeFactory());
    beanTester.getFactoryCollection().addFactory(UUID.class,
            new ExecutionUUIDFactory());
    beanTester.testBean(getBeanInstance().getClass());
}
```

Then you just define the custom factories that you want (in this example)

```
/**
 * Concrete Factory that creates a LocalDateTime.
 */
class LocalDateTimeFactory implements Factory<LocalDateTime>
{
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime create()
    {
        return LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}

/**
 * Concrete Factory that creates a UUID.
 */
class ExecutionUUIDFactory implements Factory<UUID>
{
    @Override
    public UUID create()
    {
        return UUID.randomUUID();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom factory for your field:

```
   class HostNamesFactory implements Factory<String[]> {
        @Override
        public String[] create() {
            return new String[] {"host1", "host2", "host3"};
        }
    }
```

Then use this factory when you create your custom configuration and pass it to the bean tester:

```
    Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().overrideFactory("hostNames", new HostNamesFactory()).build();
    new BeanTester().testBean(Machine.class, configuration);
```

I am agree this is not the perfect solution but at least the property getter and setter will be tested.

Comment: This works for BeanTester().testBean(), but is there any equivalent which works for the EqualsMethodTester() and HashCodeMethodTester() in the same package? EqualsMethodTester() accepts a Configuration, but doesn't seem to use it. HashCodeMethodTester() doesn't accept a Configuration at all...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144425/custom-attribute-factories-for-meanbean-equalsmethodtester-and-hashcodemethodtes

Comment: can we overrideFactory method based on the object type ..? I have Entities with sql TimeStamp data types.

Comment: Yes, we can override,  use below code.
public class LocalDateTimeFactory implements Factory<java.sql.Timestamp> {
 
 public Timestamp create()
    {            
  return Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now());
    }

}

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to my test, but it had no arrays (and there is no question for that, hence adding it here, as it might help people with similar issues).

My Class was annotated with @Data and @AllArgsConstructor. Members were of String and Double type only.

The solution was to add a @NoArgsConstructor to the class.